# Passing a variable through a anchor link is showing unidentified index error

Tags: php, mysqli

HTML page to PHP page: (works like a charm)

```
<a href="usercouponadd.php?id=<?php echo $row2['id'];?>" class="addbutton" ><strong>Add</strong></a>
```

PHP #1 to another PHP #2 page : (shows a error)

```
echo '<a href="usercouponaddtopay.php?couponvalue=<?php echo $row[\'couponvalue\'];?>"></a>';
```

PHP #2 variable initialization: (Un identifies couponvalue index)

```
$usercouponinhand = $_GET["couponvalue"];
```

Which put me in a confusing state of whether what did i missed...
I have kinda brainstormed 4 hours in it. Any suggestions are welcome..

Comment: Maybe you have some rewriting rules that do not pass on get parameters?

Comment: @arkascha  should i post the full script in the question.. will that help?

Comment: No, rewriting rules are defined on the level of the http server, not within the php scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `<?php` inside a string literal. If you view the source of the web page, you'll see that it's actually putting `<?php echo $row['couponvalue'];?>` in the URL, not the value of the variable. `<?php` can only be used when you're outside the PHP scripting mode.

So it should be:

```
echo '<a href="usercouponaddtopay.php?couponvalue={$row['couponvalue']""></a>';
```

or

```
?>
<a href="usercouponaddtopay.php?couponvalue=<?php echo $row['couponvalue'];?>"></a>
<?php
```